# Intellij Idea: Adding JARS or directories into project dependencies but no effects

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I intend to add dependence into my project in Intellij Idea so that the code could be indexed correctly in the IDE. I add the directory where the dependence source code is in File->Project Structure->Modules->Jars or directories(by clicking the plus button at the right side of the Dependencies tab). The dependence source code seems to be added successfully:
[image]

But obviously no effects at all in the IDE:
[image]

and the **Cannot resolve symbol** error still:
[image]

That is realy wierd to me.
Moreover, it works if I add jars rather than source code!

I have no idea how this could happen...

Comment: If https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/working-with-module-dependencies.html doesn't work, file a bug at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA with the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [idea.log](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/207241085) attached.

Comment: I already started a issue:https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-181897

Comment: "However, it works if I add jars rather than source code." There is your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Module dependencies work on the compiled `.class` files only (and jars containing `.class` files). They will not work if you add sources directory/jar.

In order to depend on the sources you need to build them first.

In IntelliJ IDEA you can create a new module and put your sources in the [Sources Root](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/configuring-content-roots.html) of this module so that IDE can compile them.

Then you can [configure](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/working-with-module-dependencies.html) your main module to depend on this module containing the sources for you've just created.

Comment: Exactly right. I just found this rule last night 0.0